Bounding an integral in Tao's proof of Stirling's formula
On his blog Terence Tao gives a proof of Stirling's formula here
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/
At one point he needs to bound the integral
$$-\int_0^x \frac{(x-y)}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2}\,dy$$
and he claims that this has a uniform upper bound $-cx^2$ for some $c>0$ when $|x|\le \sqrt{n}$.
I'm not being able to show this for $x<0$. Would appreciate some help.

You are interested in an upper bound of $$I=-\int_0^x \frac{(x-y)}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2}\,dy\,.$$
We first show the inequality for $x<0$.
We use the inequality (valid for $y \leq 0$)
$$\frac{1}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2} \geq  1\,.$$
With this, we obtain the bound
$$I \leq -  \int_0^x (x-y)\,dy = - \frac{x^2}{2}\,.$$
In the opposite case $x>0$,
we use the inequality (valid for $0\leq y\leq |x| \leq \sqrt{n}$)
$$\frac{1}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2} \geq  \frac{1}{4}\,.$$
With this, we obtain the bound
$$I \leq - \frac{1}{4} \int_0^x (x-y)\,dy = - \frac{x^2}{8}\,.$$

I'm not sure the first part works. When x<0 the end-points of the integral are reversed, fixing that gives a minus sign so the comparison does not work right.

@JyotirmoyBhattacharya: the factor $(x-y)$ is then also negative. So everything seems to work?

It does. Thanks!

To establish the bound on the integral
$$I = \int_{-\alpha}^{1-\alpha} \frac{dx}{(1+x)(1+\alpha+x)^2}$$
for $\alpha > 1$ with $\alpha \approx 1$, we first adjust the limits of integration to handle the negative value of $\alpha$. By changing the direction of integration, the integral becomes
$$I = \int_{\alpha-1}^{\alpha} \frac{dx}{(1+x)(1+\alpha+x)^2}$$
This re-expression allows us to integrate with $x$ increasing from $\alpha-1$ to $\alpha$, which is more convenient for $\alpha > 1$.
Next, we introduce a substitution to simplify the integrand. Let $y = x + \alpha$, so $dy = dx$. When $x = \alpha-1$, $y = 2\alpha-1$, and when $x = \alpha$, $y = 2\alpha$ (since $\alpha > 1$, $2\alpha-1 > \alpha$). The integral now becomes
$$I = \int_{2\alpha-1}^{2\alpha} \frac{dy}{(1+y-\alpha)(1+y)^2}$$
Our goal is to find an upper bound for $I$ in terms of $\alpha$. To do this, we need to bound the denominator of the integrand. Since $\alpha > 1$, it follows that $y > \alpha$. Also, $y$ ranges from $2\alpha-1$ to $2\alpha$, so $y < 2\alpha$ and $y > 2\alpha-1$, implying $1+y > 2\alpha$.
Combining these, the expression inside the denominator satisfies
$$1+y-\alpha > y-\alpha > \alpha-\alpha = 0$$
and
$$(1+y)^2 > (2\alpha)^2 = 4\alpha^2$$
Therefore, the denominator $(1+y-\alpha)(1+y)^2$ is bounded between $0$ and $4\alpha^3$. To avoid division by zero and ensure $1+y-\alpha > 0$, we can restrict $\alpha$ further by choosing $\alpha < 2$ for some $\alpha > 1$, ensuring $y < 2\alpha < 4$ and thus $1+y-\alpha > 0$.
With these bounds, the integrand satisfies
$$\frac{1}{(1+y-\alpha)(1+y)^2} < \frac{1}{4\alpha^3}$$
since $\alpha > 1$. This inequality allows us to estimate $I$ from above:
$$I < \frac{1}{4\alpha^3} \int_{2\alpha-1}^{2\alpha} dy = \frac{1}{4\alpha^3}$$
This shows that $I \lesssim \alpha^{-3}$, where $\lesssim$ is a positive constant, confirming that the integral is bounded above by a negative quadratic in $\alpha$.

Can you please add something explaining how your integral is related to the integral in the question.
